A constructor needs Node::SharedPtr, but you can't run shared_from_this() in the constructor
When coding with ROS2, I would sometimes make a class whose constructor needs a rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr. Then, I would make this class be a member of a parent Node class. So something like:
class Foo
{
    Foo(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr nh)
    {}
};

class ParentNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    ParentNode()
    : Node("parent_node")
    , foo(shared_from_this())
    {}
private:
    Foo foo
}

However, I cannot call shared_from_this() inside the constructor (it throws a weak_ptr error).
I have seen others get away with it by having LifecycleNode as the parent and initializing the foo inside the on_configure() method.
Is there another way to make this work or is this just bad programming pattern?
I currently have two solutions:

Instead of taking a Node::SharedPtr, the Foo class would take Node* and you can pass this in the constructor

class Foo
{
    Foo(rclcpp::Node* nh)
    {}
};

class ParentNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    ParentNode()
    : Node("parent_node")
    , foo(this)
    {}
private:
    Foo foo
}


Make a rclcpp::TimerBase to run a function that initializes foo after the constructor

class Foo
{
    Foo()
    {}

    Foo(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr nh)
    {}
};

class ParentNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    ParentNode()
    : Node("parent_node")
    {
        timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
            500ms, std::bind(&ParentNode::initialize, this)
        );
    }
private:
    Foo foo
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;

    void initialize()
    {
        timer_->cancel();
        foo = Foo(shared_from_this());
    }
}
```


Actually quite interesting.
Following this stack overflow post, your object must first exist before you can have a pointer pointing towards it or owning it. Since you make_shared or assign new an instance of your class ParentNode (at some point in your main), shared_from_this() cannot return anything inside the constructor, because your ParentNode object does not exist yet.
As a workaround, I would not use the raw pointer or a timer that you bind a callback to. Just add a public function that does the initialization and call it after your make_shared on the object as instance_shared_ptr->initialize();. Of course, some safeguards inside your class would be good, checking if(!foo) return; before you let it do anything.
